# How to use np.setdiff1d and np.union1d on 2D array and keep the array shape

Tags: python, numpy, set

I have three 2D arrays with the same nrows but ncols differs :

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[0,2,3,4,5,np.nan,np.nan]])
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,np.nan]])
c = np.array([[4,np.nan],[0,3]])
```

I want to find the union between b and c and then find the difference between this union and a. I want to keep the structure of my data, so the union and the difference should output a 2 dimensional array like this:

```
U = union(b,c)
U -> [[1,2,3,4,np.nan],[0,2,3,np.nan,np.nan]] # the result I want
# U[0] is equal to union(b[0],c[0]) 
# U[1] is equal to union(b[1],c[1])
...
D = Diff(a,U) 
D -> [[5,6,7],[4,5,np.nan]] # the result I want
# D[0] is equal to Diff(a[0],U[0])
# D[1] is equal to Diff(a[1],U[1])
...
```

So the union and difference must be performed between subarrays. However when I use np.union1d(b,c) or np.setdiff1d(a,U) I get a flattend array.

The code below works with this example but it's too slow and I wonder if it could be improved, also it dosen't keep a rectangular shape which is problematic for the vectorized operations (and maybe there are other problems that I didn't see):

```
C = np.concatenate((b,c),axis=1)
U = np.unique(C,axis=1)
D = np.array([np.setdiff1d(a[i],U[i]) for i in range(len(a))])
```

I have tried to use np.view() to make np.setdiff1d and np.union1d read each rows as if it's an invividual variable to keep the 2d shape like this:

```
nrows, ncols = a.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)], 'formats':ncols * [a.dtype]}
A = a.copy().view(dtype)

nrows, ncols = b.shape
dtype={'names':['f{}'.format(i) for i in range(ncols)], 'formats':ncols * [b.dtype]}
B = b.copy().view(dtype)

# then i try np.union1d() with theses newly created arrays and I get an error
>>> np.union1d(A,B)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in union1d
  File "/home/abbesses/grand/miniconda3/envs/Decomp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/numpy/lib/arraysetops.py", line 777, in union1d
    return unique(np.concatenate((ar1, ar2), axis=None))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
TypeError: invalid type promotion with structured datatype(s).
```

Question: what can I do to perform theses set operations with numpy, on multidimensional arrays ?

Note: the np.nan in the various arrays are there to keep them rectangular. For example if an array has a max columns length of 10, every other columns must be 10 in length to allow vectorized calculation later, so they are filled with np.nan.

EDIT1:

I have found a way to make my output rectangular by doing this:

```
C = np.concatenate((b,c),axis=1)
U = np.unique(C,axis=1)
D = np.array([np.setdiff1d(a[i],U[i]) for i in range(len(a))])
maxNei = max(map(len, D)) # the maximum length of D array
D = [np.concatenate((k,[np.nan]*(maxNei - len(k)))) for k in D]
```

Comment: The error traceback shows us that `np.union1d` uses `np.unique` on the `concatenate((,a,b))`.  That is it makes one array from the inputs.  `concatenate` only works if the structured array dtypes are identical, which isn't the case with your arrays.

Answer (score 0):

`union1d` works on a pair of structured arrays - if they have the same dtype:

```
In [105]: dt = np.dtype('f,f,f')

In [106]: np.union1d(np.ones(3,dt), np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],dt))
Out[106]: 
array([(1., 1., 1.), (1., 2., 3.), (4., 5., 6.)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')])
```

Note that it treats each record as an 'entity'; here it removed the multiple `(1,1,1)`.  It is still 1d union.

This is equivalent to using python `set` on lists of tuples

```
In [118]: (np.ones(3,dt), np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],dt))
Out[118]: 
(array([(1., 1., 1.), (1., 1., 1.), (1., 1., 1.)],
       dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')]),
 array([(1., 2., 3.), (4., 5., 6.)],
       dtype=[('f0', '<f4'), ('f1', '<f4'), ('f2', '<f4')]))

In [119]: (np.ones(3,dt).tolist(), np.array([(1,2,3),(4,5,6)],dt).tolist())
Out[119]: 
([(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)],
 [(1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)])

In [120]: set(Out[119][0]).union(set(Out[119][1]))
Out[120]: {(1.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 2.0, 3.0), (4.0, 5.0, 6.0)}
```

### edit

Some general thoughts on `numpy` and set behavior.

Those functions that you tried to use like `np.union1d` are marked **1d** for a reason.

`np.unique` can work on 2d, but it uses a little trick. The array is transformed into a 1d structured array.  It then uses `unique1d`, where each array `record`, or `np.void` object is a multibyte "number".  As such it can be sorted and tested for uniqueness as any other 1d array.

`union1d` just does:  `unique(np.concatenate((ar1, ar2), axis=None))`

Make 2 2d int array:

```
In [213]: x, y = np.ones((2,3),int), np.zeros((4,3),int)

In [217]: np.unique(x, axis=0)
Out[217]: array([[1, 1, 1]])
```

Make views of `x` and `y` - note that it adds a dimension:

```
In [218]: dt = np.dtype('i,i,i')  
In [219]: x.view(dt)
Out[219]: 
array([[(1, 1, 1)],
       [(1, 1, 1)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])

In [220]: y.view(dt)
Out[220]: 
array([[(0, 0, 0)],
       [(0, 0, 0)],
       [(0, 0, 0)],
       [(0, 0, 0)]], dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

Now `union1d` works (because `np.concatenate((x.view(dt),y.view(dt)))` works):

```
In [221]: np.union1d(x.view(dt),y.view(dt))
Out[221]: 
array([(0, 0, 0), (1, 1, 1)],
      dtype=[('f0', '<i4'), ('f1', '<i4'), ('f2', '<i4')])
```

I haven't fully tried to understand your goals, but a couple of things stand out.

Your arrays are float dtype (because of the `np.nan`), and shapes (2,7), (2,3), and (2,2).  Testing for equality and order with `np.nan` is tricky, even impossible.  Testing floats is also unreliable, though may be ok with these floats.

Let's test `unique` on `b`:

```
In [236]: b
Out[236]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3., nan]])

In [237]: np.repeat(b,3,0)
Out[237]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3., nan],
       [ 2.,  3., nan],
       [ 2.,  3., nan]])

In [238]: np.unique(np.repeat(b,3,0),axis=0)
Out[238]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 2.,  3., nan],
       [ 2.,  3., nan],
       [ 2.,  3., nan]])
```

It didn't remove the duplicates involving `nan`.

Since you want to do the union row by row, this row iteration makes most sense:

```
In [239]: [np.union1d(i,j) for i,j in zip(b,c)]
Out[239]: [array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan]), array([ 0.,  2.,  3., nan])]
```

Yes, python iteration is BAD, but if the alternative is nothing?  Remember `union1d` is **1d**

```
In [241]: [np.setdiff1d(i,j) for i,j in zip(a, Out[239])]
Out[241]: [array([5., 6., 7.]), array([ 4.,  5., nan])]
```

A variant on the `union1d` is to join `b,c` horizontally, and do a row by row `unique`:

```
In [266]: [np.unique(i) for i in (np.hstack((b,c)))]
Out[266]: [array([ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4., nan]), array([ 0.,  2.,  3., nan])]
```

Since the rows have different numbers of elements, a "vectorized" version is impossible.

`setdiff1d` makes use of `in1d`, which in turn makes the 2 arrays `unique`, concatenates them, and then does an argsort.  Lots more sorting :)

### set

Python `set` uses hashing, as used with `dict`.  In this small case it's actually faster:

```
In [247]: timeit [set(i).union(j) for i,j in zip(b,c)]
10.2 µs ± 77.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [248]: timeit [np.union1d(i,j) for i,j in zip(b,c)]
101 µs ± 1.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

`numpy` set code, based on sorting, is not particularly fast.

continuing with the `set`:

```
In [258]: [set(j).difference(i) for i,j in zip(Out[246],a)]
Out[258]: [{5.0, 6.0, 7.0}, {nan, nan, 4.0, 5.0}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not what I want. To clarify: I want that the union or difference be performed between each subarrays of a pair of arrays. So for example with b = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,np.nan]])
c = np.array([[4,np.nan],[0,3]]) I want the operation done between b[0] and c[0] (that gives result[0]), then b[1] and c[1] (to give result[1]).

Comment: My focus was on the subject line - set operations on structured arrays.

Comment: Yes and thank you for thant. I have tried to change the dtypes of my arrays. I gave the dtype the same shape of my array like this: {'names': [['f0', 'f1', 'f2'], ['f0', 'f1', 'f2']], 'formats': ((dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64')), (dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'), dtype('float64')))}
But np.dtype work with Tuple of size 2 apparently: >>> B= np.array(b,np.dtype(dtype))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Tuple must have size 2, but has size 3

Comment: I don't think you understand the syntax for defining compound dtypes, nor their purpose.  In a structured array you effectively replace the columns dimension of a 2d array with `fields`.  The result is a 1d array which treats each 'row' as a unit, as a `record`.

Comment: Ok so this dosen't solve my problem

Comment: I edited my answer, looking at/for alternatives, and basically came to the conclusion that you have to work "row by row", whether you use the numpy set functions or the faster Python `set`.  Since results for each row set will differ in size, there's no 2d "vectorized" solution.  The numpy set functions are labeled **1d** for a reason.